# RangeValidator cannot work with decimal value (c#, Enterprise Library)

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, enterprise-library

Hello Stackoverflow fellas!

I'm working with Enterprise Library 5.0 and I'm trying to validate if a decimal value is from the specified range, but there's no obvious way to do it

e.g

```
[RangeValidator(0, RangeBoundaryType.Exclusive, 1, RangeBoundaryType.Ignore)]
```

works only for int, double & float.

I'm exactly looking for the equivalent of the Visual Basic's line of code:

```
<RangeValidator(GetType(Decimal), "0.00", RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, "0.00", RangeBoundaryType.Ignore, MessageTemplate := "Value must be greater than 0.")>
```

I don't want to cast, because of the precision.
Has anyone overcame this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved it the following decimal way:

```
[RangeValidator(typeof(decimal), "0.00", RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, "1.00", RangeBoundaryType.Ignore)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work but try making your range values decimal:

```
[RangeValidator(0.0, RangeBoundaryType.Exclusive, 1.0, RangeBoundaryType.Ignore)]
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
[RangeValidator(0.0m, RangeBoundaryType.Exclusive, 1.0m, RangeBoundaryType.Ignore)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RangeValudatorAttribute` class doesn't have a constructor that supports decimals directly - VB may indirectly cast the

You can use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee779118%28v=pandp.60%29.aspx) that takes `double` values instead:

```
[RangeValidator(0.0, RangeBoundaryType.Exclusive, 1.0, RangeBoundaryType.Ignore)]
```

Since `0.0` and `1.0` can be represented *exactly* in binary you shouldn't have a precision issue when comparing to `decimal` values.